# How do i link an object inside another object, assuming both are the same class and both are in an arraylist?

Tags: java

Lets say i have

```java
class Customer{
  int phone; //unique for each customer
  Customer upline; //ref to another customer object
}
```

and i have an arraylist of customer,

```java
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
```

assume customerList[3] is the following

```java
customerList[3]{
  //013-456789
  //customerList[2]
}
```

I understand on how to implement this. when registering customer, i will enter the uplineCustomer phone number and get the array number.

After that, use `customerList[3].setUplineCustomer(customerList[2])`

But what if later im removing a object from customerList array? eg `customerList.remove(1)`

Do i need to reupdate everything? Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: You say `customerList[]`, but I read that as an array of `customerList`. Posting real code examples instead of pseudo-code might help clarify that. That said, I would be remiss to mix the functionality of the `Customer` with the container that holds it. Unless there's a reason to have Customers linked to other customers, the container for them need not be involved at all. If you do keep those references, then there's no need for a separate container for the customers in the end, the `Customer` object can simply hold them.

Comment: (It sounds like you're perhaps trying to implement a linked list, but I'll wait for more info)

Comment: Hi rogue, tq for answering. Ive updated the code to be more nicely. I dont actually have a code, since this is only a theoritical question. That being said, i realize how to do this. instead of using a ref to another object, i can simply clone the object, thus creating a new copy. then if i need to identify them back, i can just use method customer.equal() to trace back which is which. doesnt feel like this is good practice however. tq regardless!

Comment: @fdhl Why does a customer reference another customer? What is the purpose of the `upline` field? Also, why is the phone number an `int` value? It should be something like a string instead (or maybe even a new class with "local number" and "area code", if necessary...).

Comment: Don't confuse ArrayLists for arrays, those are two _completely_ different things. Arrays are language primitives for fixed sized, typed slot lists that must be (pre)allocated to a specific number of slots, indexed using square brackets. ArrayLists are a datastructure _object_ that is not sized and allows arbitrary content (unless restricted via generics) and that you interact with using methods, just like any other object. If you show ArrayList code first, and then array code after, the only proper answer is "if this is the level you're at right now, learn the rest of Java basics first".

Comment: Short answers: `Do i need to reupdate everything?`: Probably, if you don't want customer 3 to refer to customer 2 anymore after it's removed from the list; but you know your requirements better than we do. — `Is there a smarter way of doing this?`: No

Comment: Tough to say without knowing the exact requirements but probably having some  abstraction on Customer class which provides the ability to specify if the customer is active or not in the list.